# HTTP and HTTPS at separate domains

Tags: http, ssl, https

guys

What are the pros/cons for

1. HTTP and HTTPS are on different domains. i.e. HTTPS url contains something like 'secure' as a subdomain
2. HTTP and HTTPS are on the same domain and that's the only one difference between domains.

I like 2) more, but what do you think about that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, 2) is probably better from the user point of view because

- it makes sure the domains are the same,
- browsers raise a very visible flag when using https, so user cannot miss it anyway.

From the developer POV, 1) can make sense if a company wants to gather all sensitive transactions on a single domain, served by a secured server (however this can be achieved also by redirection, so 1) can be implemented while keeping 2) as front-end)